# Android Widgets callbacks on orientation change

Tags: android, widget, android-widget, screen-orientation, android-remoteview

I have a widget that renders generated bitmap as a background. This bitmap is generated with accordance to widget width and height provided in a Bundle by AppWidgetProvider. Some launchers (eg. Samsung default launcher) calling onAppWidgetOptionsChanged and onUpdate callbacks of AppWidgetProvider on orientation change but some do not call any AppWidgetProvider callback at all (eg. NovaLauncher). Because of that widget redraw method is not called with updated width and height and my background bitmap is not rendered properly.

Is there any way to redraw widget consistently on orientation change in every launcher or it all depends on launcher implementation?